# Multiple setTimeout : Parallel or Recursive?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, event-loop

Assume this situation, I need to do some work in **different time intervals**.

So I got an array to describe the running plan like this.

```
var jobs = [ [ "a", 10 ], [ "b", 20 ], [ "c", 25 ], [ "d", 30 ], [ "e", 15 ], ... ];
```

Then here comes the question. Should I put **ALL** tasks into Web Apis 
 in once like this?

```
var timer = 0;
jobs.forEach( job => {
    timer += job[1] * 100;
    window.setTimeout( () => console.log( job[0] ), timer );
} );
jobs = undefined;
```

Nothing left in JavaScript space, seems clean, but many Web Apis registered.

Or should I using common recursive way like this?

```
var tick = () => {
    if ( ! jobs.length ) return;
    else job = jobs.shift();

    window.setTimeout( () => {
        tick();
        console.log( job[0] );
    }, job[1] * 100 );
}

tick();
```

There's always an big array left in JavaScript space, but only 1 Web Api are used.

Or a global interval loop like this?

```
var timer = 0;
window.setInterval( () => {
    if ( ! jobs.length ) return ;
    else if ( ++ timer >= jobs[0][1] ) {
        timer = 0;
        console.log( jobs[0][0] );
        jobs.shift();
    }
}, 100 );
```

A custom event-loop, just like the recursive way I think.

So, is there any difference between these three ways?

Anyway, this situation is a long long time execution browser based page.

Not strictly require the time accurate, but need to use CPU/Memory as less as possible.

Which method saves memory much after the web page is opened for example, one month?

Comment: `Should I` that depends on what you want from your code (efficiency, reliability...)

Comment: @JackBashford efficiency at the most, reliability not that important in my case. :)

Comment: **For additional**, job queue is run in sequence, jobs[n][1] minimum is 1, it can't be 0.